# Woo Commerce Checkout Paypal things dont appear to be working

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and when you go to checkout it comes up with the following error message:

[image]

The issue is that I don't even have PayPal selected as a payment option so I am confused about why this is even coming up. Could it be because it's a http site and not https?

Comment: disable the PayPal option from woo commerce payment settings

Comment: Have some errors?

Comment: @OMiShah I tried this, and it still comes up

Comment: @Dmitry This is all I get...

Comment: That's weird. using any cache plugin or PayPal plugin? you can try clearing cache and disabling the plugin.

Comment: @OMiShah Using a cache plugin but I've just disabled that and tried it and still no luck, it is a very weird one...

Comment: Try check error_log